# SQL - 2 equal queries differently written are not working the same

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

Can the below query 1 be written as the Query 2? If yes, they are not working as same.
If not, then I need the LINQ version for the query 2.

Query 1:

```
select c.Name as 'Country', s.Name as 'State', city.Name as 'City' 
from CountryRegion c,CountryRegion s,CountryRegion city 
where  city.Id=11 and s.Id=city.CountryRegionParentId and c.Id=s.CountryRegionParentId
```

Query 2:

```
select c.Name as 'Country', s.Name as 'State', city.Name as 'City' 
from CountryRegion as c inner join CountryRegion as s on c.Id=s.Id
inner join CountryRegion as city on s.Id=c.Id
where  city.Id=11 and s.Id=city.CountryRegionParentId and c.Id=s.CountryRegionParentId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a mistake in Query 2, since you're using a different join criteria then the criteria in your where clause (which does not really make sense). If you rewrite Query 2 to the following, it should be completely equivalent to Query 1:

```
select c.Name as 'Country', s.Name as 'State', city.Name as 'City' 
from 
    CountryRegion as city inner join 
    CountryRegion as s on s.Id = city.CountryRegionParentId inner join
    CountryRegion as c on c.Id = s.CountryRegionParentId
where  city.Id=11
```